GitHub PAT vs. Fine-grained Token Query
I have a couple of general questions regarding GitHub API tokens.
Right now we have a fine-grained API token with the following permissions created for some automation we use:

Code scanning alerts -> Access: Read and write
Metadata -> Access: Read only

This gives us the required permissions to call the following API endpoints:

List repository languages
Upload an analysis as SARIF data

As this is a fine-grained token this limits the scope to a single Organization. We want to run the same automation on multiple Organizations and want to replace with a PAT.
My questions are:

What is the minimum set of permissions required to replicate what we have with the fine-grained token?
Is it just security_events?
If it is just security_events, would this PAT have any additional API privileges that the fine-grained token does not have?
Is the default rate-limit the same for PAT and fine-grained tokens?

